# How to build a query in Laravel

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I'm new to laravel and have some problems with the understanding how the query builder is working.

I created a laravel project and connect it successfuly to the sqlsrv. And now i would like to retrive data from the database.

For first without models just in the `wep.php` for understanding.

```
Route::get('/tasks', function () {
    $tasks = DB::table('WebShops')->get();
    dd($tasks);
});
```

This is working it shows me all the db rows.

Now i would like to filter the rows with `find` command and i get an error:

```
Route::get('/tasks/{ShopID}', function($ShopID){
    $task = DB::table('WebShops')->find($ShopID);
    dd($task);
});
```

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL
>   Server]
>   Invalid column name "id". (SQL: select top 1 * from
>   [WebShops] where [id] = 1)

This is confusing because i assigned find to the `ShopID` and now i get the error that is searching for an `id`. Why ?

I tried also this:

```
 Route::get('/tasks/{ShopID}', function($ShopID){
        $task = DB::table('WebShops')->where('ShopID', $ShopID);
        //dd($task->name); here comes also an error
        dd($task);

 });
```

This is showing me a big array with the data that i don't really understand.

[image]

My DB look like this:
[image]

Comment: `$task = DB::table('WebShops')->where('ShopID', $ShopID)->get();`

Comment: You beat me to it @u_mulder :D

Comment: You ought to create a Model and just call it for easier and convenient way. E.G : $webshops = App\WebShop::all(); // this will call all the data in table 'WebShop'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're new to Laravel it's a good opportunity to start building your models instead of using the query builder.

```
class WebShop extends Model {
     //You need this because by convention Laravel assumes table names are snake_cased (it would look for web_shops)
     protected $table = "WebShops"; 

     // You need this because by convention the primary key is called id.
     protected $primaryKey = 'ShopID';

}
```

Then the following code would work:

```
$shop = WebShop::find($id);
```

[Laravel's Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent) is a good read on more info.

Answer (score 5):

In code

```
Route::get('/tasks/{ShopID}', function($ShopID){
    $task = DB::table('WebShops')->find($ShopID);
    dd($task);
});
```

you try to find rows where **what** field is equal to `$ShopID` value?

Laravel doesn't know. So, it assumes, you have field `id` as a primary key. As you don't have such field, according to your table structure, you have an error.

According to manual, you can redefine primary key with:

```
public $primarykey = 'ShopID';
```

in your **model** file.

In second attempt, to receive collection of records - add `get()`:

```
Route::get('/tasks/{ShopID}', function($ShopID){
    $task = DB::table('WebShops')->where('ShopID', $ShopID)->get();
    dd($task);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

find is by default looking for the column id in the table if you are using "ShopID" as the primary key you must define in the model like

```
protected $primaryKey = 'ShopID';
```

after that it's working

```
$task = DB::table('WebShops')->find($ShopID);
```

Comment: How do i define a primery key in model so that the find command looks after it ?

Comment: protected $primaryKey = 'ShopID';

Comment: unfortunately when i create a model and give it to the web.php `$tasks = App\WebShops::all();` i'm getting an error `SQLSTATE[42S02]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid objectname "web_shops". (SQL: select * from [web_shops])`. Why is he serach in a different table ? My table look like this `WebShops`

Comment: how do I create a model through CLI?

Answer (score 0):

```php
class WebShop extends Model {
     //You need this because by convention Laravel assumes table names are snake_cased (it would look for web_shops)
     protected $table = "WebShops"; 

     // You need this because by convention the primary key is called id.
     protected $primaryKey = 'ShopID';
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).